# How can I search for rows "around" a given string value?

Tags: sql-server-2005, t-sql

I have a table with a `varchar()` field called `identifier` that contains a unique name for the entity.

I'd like to search the table and find the rows with a given identifier *and* up to 10 rows on either side of that identifier, sorted alphabetically (i.e., the searched-for identifier and its neighboring rows on either side).

What is the best way to formulate this in SQL Server 2005? I'm guessing there's some `ROW_NUMBER()` magic that can do this, but I'm not finding any go-by queries to do this sort of thing.

This is as close as I can get so far, but performance is *terrible*:

```
WITH 
  allrows AS (
   SELECT *, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(ORDER BY identifier DESC) AS RN
       FROM mytable
  ),
  centerrow AS (
    SELECT RN AS CRN FROM allrows WHERE identifier = 'MyValue'
  )
SELECT * FROM allrows, centerrow 
WHERE RN BETWEEN (centerrow.CRN - 10) AND (centerrow.CRN + 10)
```

The table has over 2 million records, and the identifier field can be as long as 1000 characters.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This answer is a bit more compilerfriendly

```
declare @e table(identifier varchar(5))
insert @e values (0),(1),(2),(3),(4)

SELECT * FROM(
SELECT top 2 * 
FROM @e WHERE 
identifier >= '2' 
ORDER BY identifier asc) a
UNION ALL 
SELECT * FROM (
SELECT top 1 * 
FROM @e 
WHERE identifier < '2' 
ORDER BY identifier desc ) b
```

Comment: I hadn't considered a UNION, my head was stuck in trying to do it within a single SELECT. I chose this answer over the other similar one since it also handles sorting the final result set.

Comment: What makes this more "compiler friendly"? I missed the sort requirement, but I cannot see how this is any different, "compiler-friendly"-wise, than mine. In fact, other than adding the sort requirement, it may as well be copypasta.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA your script does not compile, I don't mind you getting the point. But your script is invalid as it is.

Comment: Haha - I see what I did there; I put ORDER BY in the SELECTs. My bad. I really should type these in a proper editor instead of the answer box. Bleh. Maybe next time you could say "The other solution won't compile". I thought you were implying optimization rather than actual compilation. Silly me.

Comment: @PittsburghDBA I was also considering just fixing your scipt instead. It was almost there. I vote you up instead for having the right idea.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT TOP 11 * FROM MyTable WHERE identifier >= 'My Value' ORDER BY identifier ASC
UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 10 * FROM MyTable WHERE identifier < 'My Value' ORDER BY identifier DESC
```

Comment: Might want to have both ascending and descending indexes on the `identifier`.